Is it possible to package Salesforce permission sets that grant permissions to custom apps and/or tabs?
Whenever a package is created in Salesforce, I only give permissions to the objects and its fields, and when the package is installed, only for the admin; the other users cannot access the app unless they are given app and tab permissions separately so instead, can I give app level and tab level permission to a permission set and create a package because later it is simple to assign this permission set to the other users instead of providing app permission and tab permissions. Will there be any salesforce restrictions or issues if I package a salesforce app that grants permissions to custom app and/or tabs?
Thanks in Advance.
